Edit Magento 2 Product Category selection checkbox template which coming from UI component
I have created a category custom attribute with Yes and No value. With that attribute value I need to disable category selection at Magento product edit/creation section dropdown box. As Magento admin product page created with UI component I need to overwrite that category dropdown selection checkbox in my custom module to disable it as per attribute value for that category.

I not able to find the template file which are responsible for this change.
